# Angular 2 Karma tests have started to fail can't capture browser

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular2-testing

This seems like a project setup problem in someway.  This was working previously.  I don't have the knowledge that these error messages help me to start.  Does anyone have some advice on where to start diagnosing the problem?

```
21 05 2017 07:42:55.094:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
21 05 2017 07:42:55.110:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
21 05 2017 07:42:55.110:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
21 05 2017 07:42:55.118:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                        ERROR in /Users/jgreenaw/WebstormProjects/legalcoveapp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts (41,33): Cannot find name 'Node'.

ERROR in /Users/jgreenaw/WebstormProjects/legalcoveapp/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form.d.ts (69,22): Cannot find name 'Event'.

ERROR in /Users/jgreenaw/WebstormProjects/legalcoveapp/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.d.ts (74,22): Cannot find name 'Event'.

ERROR in /Users/jgreenaw/WebstormProjects/legalcoveapp/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.d.ts (58,26): Cannot find name 'KeyboardEvent'.

ERROR in /Users/jgreenaw/WebstormProjects/legalcoveapp/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts (81,26): Cannot find name 'KeyboardEvent'.
```

Comment: Can you find an earlier commit that does work?

Comment: good question, i reverted to a previous commit 5 days ago labeled "got tests to work", and it failed with same error.  Something to note, i get the same problem in my cloud9 environment, but there i would expect this.

Comment: Maybe delete your node_modules/ and run npm install again with the old commit? This sort of thing is why I like continuous integration as it weeds out environment-specific problems.

Answer (score 5):

After upgrading my Angular lib versions, my Karma tests too started to fail which led me to the this question. After verifying the @angular/cli versions, now 1.1.2, match between global and the local project the following may also be required:

Update your *src/tsconfig.spec.json* by adding "dom" to the lib array:

```
"lib": ["es2016", "dom"],
```

Comment: +1 Fixed for me. can't believe, the problem was that simple. Also have to say that angular cli error logs are horrible and fearsome. I fled from them wandering looking for other options like web-pack and typescript and wasted two days.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move forward past the problem, but not identify the root cause by doing the following.

- sync angular/cli project and global versions to latest: 1.0.4
- rm node_modules which I had done before, but [reading this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli). I was missing `npm cache clean`
- `npm install`

Thanks @MatthewDaly for the useful suggestions and questions.

Answer (score 0):

If running karma test from your IDE (for example, IntelliJ IDEA) and your solution doesn't build/has lint errors, karma seems to not connect and just hang.

Run your tests with something like `ng test` and get that working before running from your IDE.